# Conditionally vibrate in Android notification channel

Tags: android, notifications, vibration

I made an app that vibrates periodically. But I want the device to vibrate only if the variable YYYY is true. My problem is then how to enable/disable the vibration.

I created the channel with

```
NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
chan.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0,200,200,200});
chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
```

I cannot do

```
chan.enableVibration(YYYY);
```

or

```
chan.setVibrationPattern((YYYY) ? <pattern> : null);
```

since both are `Only modifiable before the channel is submitted to NotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(NotificationChannel)`.

Is there any way of doing this without recreating the whole notification each time?

Comment: Note that the user is welcome to stop your notification vibrations via the Settings app. You might consider not putting vibrations on the notifications, but instead vibrating the device yourself periodically.

Comment: It is not an "important vibration", just informative. Yet, yours is certainly a possibility. I thought there would be a way of doing this through the notification without much gymnastics. Thanks!

Comment: If it were a one-time vibration, you could have two channels, one with and one without vibration. That won't work great for your case, as it would require you to re-raise the notification periodically, which you are trying to avoid.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion, and works perfectly, once I switched from `Notification.Builder` to `NotificationCompat.Builder` to `.setSilent(true)`. Thanks!